# update query is giving an error

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have written a c# code to update a MS Access table data, but it is showing an error "Syntax error in update statement".

```
string sql = "update Users set Name='" + txtUser_Name.Text + "',Password='"
    + txtPassword.Text + "'where Name='" + usr + "'";
```

Please tell me the right code.

Comment: `Name` is a reserved word. Try putting square brackets around it, `[Name]`, or fully qualifying it with the table name, `Users.Name`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work

```
string sql = "update Users set Name='" + txtUser_Name.Text +
    "', Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "' where Name='" + usr + "'";
```